# Using celery and rabbitmq to execute a task on annother server

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

Currently we are working on a Python3 web-project where we have to execute a task for our pyramid application. The celery worker is located on another server.
Our question is: How can we execute our task by using that worker on the other server and get the result. We'd have to use celery, rabbitMQ and amqp.

We already can execute a task when the worker is located at the same server as our pyramid project. Can anyone help us or give an example of how we can fix this problem. Cause we don't really know how to begin.

[image: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/1051/drawing1x.jpg]

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is the actual problem? Sending messages and receiving them is the primary usage of MQ's like RabbitMQ.

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps is a pretty good resource for getting started.

Answer (score 2):

The [Celery First Steps](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps) should be a good place to begin. If you don't have experience with RabbitMQ you may want to try Redis first.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I have used the send_task method to use a task on another server. and I had already read the first steps it is a very good begin to learn Celery.
Thanks all for the responses!!

Comment: I would explain your solution a little more if you are going to accept your own.